# JS and HTML different Footer Render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile site, that uses Javascript to inject a footer (the code below just shows the final HTML that is injected into the HTML div, not the process of creating the HTML).

The problem that I am experiencing, is when I add the HTML by placing the code in the HTML `div`, the JQuery Mobile footer renders correctly, however, if I load the footer using Javascript's `innerHTML` variable, it becomes distorted. Any ideas why this happens?

Finalized Footer HTML:

```
<footer data-role="footer" data-id="navFooter" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar" class="nav-footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" id="LandmarksTab" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-icon="custom">Landmarks</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" id="MoreTab" data-icon="custom">More</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Sample Code:

Footer Placed via Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/42kN6/

Footer Placed via HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/7Xu7b/1/

Comment: `$("[data-role=footer]").toolbar();` is what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/42kN6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `.enhanceWithin()` on the element( div ) that just received new content, it should style fine:

```
$('#bottomTabBar').enhanceWithin();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/42kN6/3/)

Comment: 10 min... i'm am looking for a solution to this post. GJ :)

Comment: Which post? It already has a solution ;) This is **the solution**

Comment: Thanks for posting, this answer works great. Does anyone know why this is required?

Comment: That's how jQM works. Whenever you add new content you have to update the layout that way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that jQM enhances the page after it's loaded.  The best way to deal with this is to use the onpagebeforecreate event or use the enhanceWithin() method if you're dynamically adding content to a page that has been already created.

Boy, people are fast around here.  Anyway, I'll post my answer since it has a bit more info and the alternate option for pagebeforecreate.

Comment: Thanks for posting this information about the enhanceWithin function.